# Is there any good plug-ins for developing javascript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin

**Duplicate:**

> [What is the best Javascript plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613988/what-is-the-best-javascript-plugin-for-eclipse)

jseclipse?

Comment: are you asking for more plugins?

Comment: so from what ehdv posted, are you looking for free plug-ins?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613988/what-is-the-best-javascript-plugin-for-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for more because [JSEclipse](http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/)  is a good plug-in.

If looking for more then [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=71174) has some you can check out.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript support that's intrinsic in the [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) plugin is quite good, though not without issues.

It's free and certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

JSEclipse is (to my knowledge) the premiere and near-only JavaScript editor for Eclipse, but it is not free, which some people might take offense to. Also troublesome is that the forum link provided on its site appears to now be defunct: A sign, perhaps, of a dying community?